# Overlay two ggplot2 objects in single figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have previously tried to ask for help but did not actually solve my problem.
More info can be found here:  (you can find the data-set here) [Survival analysis combining survfit and ggplot objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442502/survival-analysis-combining-survfit-and-ggplot-objects)

Unfortunately I am unable to produce a solid example to post as my code is heavily based on external programs. I am positive though that my question can be answered regardless.

I reach a point where I create 2 ggplot2 objects that need to be combined to a single figure, one overlayed on top of the other.

Namely, one km.plot which is of class:

```
> class(km.plot$plot)   
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

and two:

```
> class(surv.plot)   
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

Both share same attributes

km.plot$plot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5qmm.png

surv.plot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCUOR.png

My question is how can I combine the resulting plots in a single plot? That is, to have both surv.plot and km.plot$plot overlayed over each other.

Following another user's suggestion of doing the following results in an error:

```
 km.plot$plot + surv.plot$layers[[1]]
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'label' not found
```

I assume this error has to do with the following few lines

```
 > surv.plot$layers
 [[1]]
 mapping: y = ~mean, group = ~label, colour = ~label 
 geom_line: na.rm = FALSE
 stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
 position_identity 

 ggplot(data, aes(x=t)) +
 geom_line(aes(y= mean, group= label, colour= label), size=1.5) +
```

but I also added, inherit.aes = FALSE but did not fix my issue.

I also checked:

```
> head(surv.plot)
$`data`
curve           t      mean        lci       uci label
1    weibull  0.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000  Cabo
2    weibull  0.05514645 0.9995771 0.99816278 0.9999721  Cabo
3    weibull  0.11029289 0.9990793 0.99646259 0.9999098  Cabo
4    weibull  0.16543934 0.9985407 0.99479769 0.9998211  Cabo
5    weibull  0.22058579 0.9979715 0.99316001 0.9997176  Cabo



 > head(km.plot)
 $`plot`

 $`data.survplot`
 time n.risk n.event n.censor      surv    std.err     upper     lower
 1   0.4271047     79       0        1 1.0000000 0.00000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 2   1.0841889     78       1        0 0.9871795 0.01290349 1.0000000 0.9625264
 3   1.3470226     77       1        0 0.9743590 0.01836796 1.0000000 0.9399054
 4   3.9753593     76       1        0 0.9615385 0.02264554 1.0000000 0.9197944
 5   4.0082136     75       1        0 0.9487179 0.02632491 0.9989527 0.9010094
```

I am baffled. I am almost certain that this can be done as both objects are basically identical in terms of structure so I see no reason why this cannot be done. But I have spent quite some time on it with no hope. I really hope somebody can direct me!

Thank you for taking the time to read this post

Comment: 1) A question should be self contained, try not to link to data in another question. 2) It is almost impossible that your problem should not be reproducible by an MCVE [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . You have two data sets, and both are readable and therefore reproducible by R. Give us some of those data, and then we might be able to help. We also don't need the full data , just some snippets with the relevant columns.

Comment: Also, how is this question different from your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477338/overlay-different-ggplot2-objects