# Overlay different ggplot2 objects

Tags: r, survival, ggplot2

I have previously tried to ask for help but did not actually solve my problem.
More info can be found here:  (you can find the data-set here) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442502/survival-analysis-combining-survfit-and-ggplot-objects

Unfortunately I am unable to produce a solid example to post as my code is heavily based on external programs. I am positive though that my question can be answered regardless.

I reach a point where I create 2 ggplot2 objects that need to be combined to a single figure, one overlayed on top of the other.

Namely, one km.plot which is of class:

> class(km.plot$plot)
>       [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5qmm.png) "gg"     "ggplot"

and two:

> class(surv.plot)
>       [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5qmm.png) "gg"     "ggplot"

Both share same attributes

km.plot$plot
[image]

surv.plot
[image]

My question is how can I combine the resulting plots in a single plot? That is, to have both surv.plot and km.plot$plot overlayed over each other.

Following another user's suggestion of doing the following results in an error:

```
 km.plot$plot + surv.plot$layers[[1]]
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'label' not found
```

I assume this error has to do with the following few lines

```
 > surv.plot$layers
 [[1]]
 mapping: y = ~mean, group = ~label, colour = ~label 
 geom_line: na.rm = FALSE
 stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
 position_identity 

 ggplot(data, aes(x=t)) +
 geom_line(aes(y= mean, group= label, colour= label), size=1.5) +
```

but I also added, inherit.aes = FALSE but did not fix my issue.

I also checked:

```
> head(surv.plot)
$`data`
curve           t      mean        lci       uci label
1    weibull  0.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000  Cabo
2    weibull  0.05514645 0.9995771 0.99816278 0.9999721  Cabo
3    weibull  0.11029289 0.9990793 0.99646259 0.9999098  Cabo
4    weibull  0.16543934 0.9985407 0.99479769 0.9998211  Cabo
5    weibull  0.22058579 0.9979715 0.99316001 0.9997176  Cabo



 > head(km.plot)
 $`plot`

 $`data.survplot`
 time n.risk n.event n.censor      surv    std.err     upper     lower
 1   0.4271047     79       0        1 1.0000000 0.00000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 2   1.0841889     78       1        0 0.9871795 0.01290349 1.0000000 0.9625264
 3   1.3470226     77       1        0 0.9743590 0.01836796 1.0000000 0.9399054
 4   3.9753593     76       1        0 0.9615385 0.02264554 1.0000000 0.9197944
 5   4.0082136     75       1        0 0.9487179 0.02632491 0.9989527 0.9010094
```

I am baffled. I am almost certain that this can be done as both objects are basically identical in terms of structure so I see no reason why this cannot be done. But I have spent quite some time on it with no hope. I really hope somebody can direct me!

Thank you for taking the time to read this post

Comment: This is a question better suited for StackOverflow and should be migrated there.

Comment: @MarkWhite can this be done by me or a moderator?

Comment: A moderator has to migrate it. You could also just copy-paste this question to StackOverflow and then delete it here. Things purely based on code and computation are off-topic here; you are likely to get a better answer on StackOverflow anyways, where the ggplot2 tag is much more popular.

Comment: @MarkWhite Tried that but there's a cap of 1 post per 90 minutes. Oh well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `surv.plot` layer contains mappings for a variable called `label` which is not included in the data for `km.plot`. You should be able to get around this by adding your `surv.plot` data as an argument to the `geom` rather than `ggplot()` when you create `surv.plot`. This way the data needed to draw the layer will "travel with" it.

We can illustrate this with simpler data. Let's first create a plot from data
with only a few columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, wt)

# This represents `km.plot`
(p <- ggplot(df1, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point())
```

[image]

Now we can try to add a layer that relies on columns not included in `df1` to
the previous plot:

```r
df2 <- mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, wt, cyl)

q1 <- ggplot(df2, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = factor(cyl)), method = "lm")

p + q1$layers[[1]]
#> Error in factor(cyl): object 'cyl' not found

q2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data = df2, aes(wt, mpg, color = factor(cyl)), method = "lm")

p + q2$layers[[1]]
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply!